# My WiFi gets deauthenticated every few minutes or seconds (Reason: 7)

Tags: wireless

My Wifi on my new Thinkpad W520 running Natty keeps dropping out and coming back on. Output from dmesg below. Any advice?

```
[30493.687552] wlan0: authenticate with e0:91:f5:ef:7b:b2 (try 1)
[30493.689127] wlan0: authenticated
[30493.689144] wlan0: associate with e0:91:f5:ef:7b:b2 (try 1)
[30493.693592] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e0:91:f5:ef:7b:b2 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[30493.693595] wlan0: associated
[31631.172868] wlan0: deauthenticated from e0:91:f5:ef:7b:b2 (Reason: 7)
[31631.211847] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
[31631.211868] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
[31631.211873] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[31631.215037] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
[31631.215042] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[31631.215044] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[31631.215046] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[31631.215049] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[31631.215051] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[31631.215053] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[31631.215055] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[31632.289638] wlan0: authenticate with e0:91:f5:ef:7b:b2 (try 1)
[31632.291262] wlan0: authenticated
[31632.291276] wlan0: associate with e0:91:f5:ef:7b:b2 (try 1)
[31632.295119] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e0:91:f5:ef:7b:b2 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[31632.295123] wlan0: associated
[31886.234836] wlan0: deauthenticated from e0:91:f5:ef:7b:b2 (Reason: 7)
[31886.306735] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
[31886.306740] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
[31886.306744] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
```

Comment: same problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem with Maverick so I installed the package `linux-backports-modules-wireless-maverick-generic` and I got a very stable system. (This packaged provided more recent wireless kernel modules than the default kernel.)

For Natty there is no package `linux-backports-modules-wireless-natty-generic`. - But you can try to install `linux-backports-modules-cw-2.6.39-natty-generic` and maybe your disconnects will go away. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is driver related problem, please post result of `"iw reg get"` and `"iw phy phy0 info"`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by compiling the driver from source after downloading it from the Realtek site - http://www.realtek.com/downloads/ - and searched for my wireless card on the field on the left.

So, to summarize: fixing this required two steps:

1. Install WICD.
2. Compile the original driver from source.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem. It was solved by installing WICD. Then uninstalling network manager. Then add WICD to your startup applications. Then reboot (essential). For me on a number of installations this has partially solved the problem

Comment: +1. Why was this down-voted?

Comment: I'm currently using wicd on Gentoo and just get this error on my home wifi access point. I think that's driver related.