# Frequent disconnects using wlan AR9285

Tags: 11.10, server, wireless, networking, atheros

I'm  getting a large number of disconnects from my wireless when I switched to oneiric server (I did not see these happen with oneiric desktop) from my AR9285 wireless LAN device.  Here is the syslog snippet:

```
Oct 17 09:43:17 weather kernel: [ 1537.329138] wlan0: deauthenticated from 00:12:17:7a:8e:42 (Reason: 7)
Oct 17 09:43:17 weather kernel: [ 1537.340409] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
Oct 17 09:43:17 weather kernel: [ 1537.340423] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
Oct 17 09:43:17 weather kernel: [ 1537.340435] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Oct 17 09:43:17 weather kernel: [ 1537.348571] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
Oct 17 09:43:17 weather kernel: [ 1537.348581] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Oct 17 09:43:17 weather kernel: [ 1537.348586] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Oct 17 09:43:17 weather kernel: [ 1537.348594] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct 17 09:43:17 weather kernel: [ 1537.348600] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct 17 09:43:17 weather kernel: [ 1537.348607] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct 17 09:43:17 weather kernel: [ 1537.348613] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Oct 17 09:43:17 weather kernel: [ 1537.348620] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
```

Here is the relevant lspci output:

```
# lspci | grep Atheros
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

I have done quite a bit of searching and saw discussions for previous versions of ubuntu that recommended installing the linux-backports-modules package.  However, this does not appear to be available for oneiric (just the headers are listed as a package).

Any advice on how to achieve a stable wireless connection for this server?  It's location mitigates against using a wired connection.

Comment: If possible post result of `dmesg` , `iw phy phy0` and `iw reg get`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following workaround, that seems to work for many people:

```
sudo su -c 'echo options ath9k nohwcrypt=1 > /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf'
```

Then just reboot. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching this one.
If the first answer given by artfwo doesn't work try this one :
https://askubuntu.com/a/55004/31838

This answer over there worked in my case (same wifi chip on Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric 64bit)

Oh! And I had to put down IPv6. IPv6 seemed to crash my connection a bit.

Hope this helps you